# How can I search a redis hash table for entities that have a particular values using spring data?

Tags: java, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I have a RedisHash table that I've model in spring data like this:

```
@RedisHash("Entity")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Entity implements Serializable {
  private String id;
  private String status;
  private String name;
}
```

I have an EntityRepository like this:

```
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends CrudRepository<Entity, String> {}
```

I then have an EntityService like this:

```
@Service 
public class EntityService {
  @Autowired
  private EntityRepository entityRepository;

  public List<Entity> getAllByName(String name) {
    // Code that gets all Entities stored in my redis table that have a certain name
  }

  public List<Entity> getAllByStatus(String status) {
    // Code that gets all Entities stored in my redis table that have a certain status
  }
```

How can I search redis for all Entities that have a certain name / have a certain status?

Comment: Did you check RediSearch?

Comment: No I haven't used that.  I'd like to do this in redis though if at all possible.

Comment: RediSearch is a module extension to Redis, is allows you to index/search hash in Redis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) and was able to solve my problem.  I added the QueryByExampleExecutor interface to my repository like this:

```
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends CrudRepository<Entity, String>, QueryByExampleExecutor<Entity> {}
```

Using the Example class I implemented getAllByName like this:

```
public List<Entity> getAllByName(String name) {
    Entity entity = new Entity();
    entity.setName(name);

    Example<Entity> example = Example.of(entity);
    entityRepository.findAll(example);
    //...
}
```