# Spring Data Redis. JPA Repository findBy is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I'm using `spring-data-redis` 2.7.5 version.

Object declaration:

```
   @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    @RedisHash("Applications")
    public class Applications implements Serializable {
        private String appName;
        private String appType;
        @Id
        private String appId;
    }
```

Controller method:

```
    @GetMapping("/filterAppsByAppsTypes")
        public List<Applications> filterAppsByAppsTypes(@RequestParam String appType) {
            List<Applications> apps = applicationRepository.findByAppType(appType);
        return apps;
    }
```

Repository:

```
    @Repository
    public interface ApplicationsRepository extends CrudRepository<Applications, String> {
        List<Applications> findByAppType(String appType);
    }
```

I have objects with the value I want to filter, but it is returning an empty array.
I tried adding `@Indexed` annotation but it does not fix it.

Comment: Hello, your code looks good for me and should work. Please share the application log during startup and the dependencies (pom.xml or gradle file).

Comment: @Mar-Z in my gradle file I have those dependencies for redis:
`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:2.7.5`
`org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:2.7.3`
`redis.clients:jedis:3.9.0`
`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis`

Also the redis server is started and there I make good connection with the redis database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60729716/how-can-i-search-a-redis-hash-table-for-entities-that-have-a-particular-values-u

Comment: What url you're using exactly for testing? Can you set a breakpoint in controller to check the parameter?

Comment: @Mar-Z 
localhost:8085/filterAppsByAppsTypes?appTypes=${appTypes}

Comment: This is wrong. Should be appType according to controller. And one string only. Not a list, right?

Comment: @Mar-Z to be exact, I need List of appTypes, but first I did it for one appType, just to make it work

Comment: @Mar-Z did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

to make this work you should include @Indexed annotation for the field you are searching by when declaring entity:

```
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.index.Indexed;

@Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    @RedisHash("Applications")
    public class Applications implements Serializable {
        private String appName;
        @Indexed
        private String appType;
        @Id
        private String appId;
    }
```

make sure it is imported from as org.springframework.data.redis.core.index.Indexed